# How to return text_html type response in Jersey

Tags: java, html, eclipse, rest, maven

I am developing a REST API using jersey jax-RS. This consumes data in JSON format and produces the output in html format.

When I set the MediaType for @Produces as TEXT_HTML and @Consumes as @APPLICATON_JSON and requested the 'GET' query on POSTMAN REST client, it gave me the following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/try2] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<org.sc.try2.model.Event>.] with root cause
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<org.sc.try2.model.Event>.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1025)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My codes :

StudentResource.java

```
package org.sc.try2.resources;

//import java.awt.Event;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
//import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.sc.try2.model.Student;
import org.sc.try2.service.StudentService;

@Path("/students")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class StudentResource {
    StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
    //EventService es = new EventService(); 


    @GET
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/viewAll")
    public List<Student> getStudents(@PathParam("studentEmail") String emailID){
        System.out.println("cmn in this method of StudentResource........ ");
        return studentService.getAllStudents(emailID);
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/viewMyProfile")
    public Student getStudent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String emailID){
        System.out.println("cmn in this method of StudentResource........ ");
        return studentService.getStudent(emailID);
    }
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/events")
    public AllEventsResource getEvents(){
        System.out.println("cmn in this method of StudentResource ");
        return  new AllEventsResource();
    }
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/myevents")
    public EventResource getStudentEvents(){
        return new EventResource();
    }


    @PUT
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/updateProfile")
    public String updateStudent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String emailID,Student student){
        //student.setEmailID(emailID);
        return studentService.updateStudent(emailID,student);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{studentEmail}/deleteStudent/{delEmail}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String emailID,@PathParam("delEmail") String delEmail){
        return studentService.removeStudent(emailID,delEmail);
    }
}
```

EventsResource.java

```
package org.sc.try2.resources;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.sc.try2.model.Event;
import org.sc.try2.service.EventService;

@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class EventResource {
EventService es = new EventService();

    @GET
    public List<Event> getMyEvents(@PathParam("studentEmail") String emailID){
        System.out.println("cmn in this method of EventsResource ");
        return es.getAllEventsForStudent(emailID);
    }

    @POST
    public String addEvent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String email,Event event){
        System.out.println("here in res add evnt..");
        return es.addEvent(email,event);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{eventId}")
    public String updateEvent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String email,@PathParam("eventId") long id,Event event){
        event.seteID(id);
        return es.updateEvent(email,id,event);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{eventId}")
    public String deleteEvent(@PathParam("studentEmail") String email,@PathParam("eventId") long id){
        return es.removeEvent(email,id);
    }
}
```

On searching about this on the internet, I did not come across any useful solution except it was mentioned to download the genson jar and add it. After adding it as external jar in Eclipse (Java EE) MAVEN Project, it still gave the same exception which I guess is due to the fact that this jar is for json MediaType and is not used in the context of html content type.

Basically, I want to produce the content as HTML. How can I do it? I am entirely new to Jersey and the concept of REST API.

Comment: How do you expect Jersey to know what HTML document to return? How is it supposed to transform a list into markup? Look up the `Viewable` class and see how it can be used with JSP to render an HTML response.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz : thanks .. Even i was thinking how jersey would convert the response to html but did not kmow where to lookup at .:)

Comment: See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html)